# Selecting an id within a class

Tags: html, css

This is my first time asking so sorry if I mess up.

So I got this code from the internet. It's a vertical tab code. I changed pretty much everything I needed... the last thing I'm wanting to change it's that the tab number 1 gets to have a `border-top-left-radius: 8px` and `border-top-right-radius: 8px;` and the tab number 7 gets to have `border-bottom-left-radius: 8px` and `border-bottom-right-radius: 8px`.

But here's the thing: I've pretty much tried every possible way to select the id of each tab and it's not letting me in any possible way to change those specific ones, it's just letting me change all of them...

And here is the link for both the html and css https://codepen.io/Zids/pen/NWWqEPd

Answer (score 0):

Here you go!

Also this might be a useful reference for referencing:

- Classes `.class`
- ID's `#id`
- Nested elements `.class #id classLessElement`

See here: [Multiple Class / ID and Class Selectors](https://css-tricks.com/multiple-class-id-selectors/)

```css
    
.tabordion {
  color: #333;
  display: block;
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  position: relative;
  width: 80%;
}

.tabordion input[name="sections"] {
  left: -9999px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -9999px;
}

.tabordion section {
  display: block;
}

.tabordion section label {
  background: #374F39;
  color:white;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  position: relative;
  width: 12px;
  z-index:100;
  
}

.tabordion section article {
  display: none;
  left: 40px;
  min-width: 300px;
  padding: 0 0 0 21px;
  position: absolute;  
  margin-top:-4em;
}

.tabordion input[name="sections"]:checked + label { 
  background: #519854;
  color: white;
  
}


.tabordion input[name="sections"]:checked ~ article {
  display: block;
}


@media (max-width: 533px) {
  
  h1 {
    width: 100%;
  }

  .tabordion {
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  .tabordion section label {
    font-size: 1em;
    width: 160px;
  }  

 .tabordion section article {
    left: 200px;
    min-width: 270px;
  } 
  
  .tabordion section article:after {
    background-color: #ccc;
    bottom: 0;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    left:-199px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 200px;

  }  
  
}


@media (max-width: 768px) {
  h1 {
    width: 96%;
  }

  .tabordion {
    width: 96%;
  }
}


@media (min-width: 1366px) {
  h1 {
    width: 70%;
  }

  .tabordion {
    width: 70%;
  }
}

.tabordion #section1 label {  
  border-top-left-radius:8px;
  border-top-right-radius:8px;
}

.tabordion #section7 label {  
  border-bottom-left-radius:8px;
  border-bottom-right-radius:8px;
}
```

```html
  
<div class="tabordion">
  <section id="section1">
    <input type="radio" name="sections" id="option1" checked>
    <label for="option1">1</label>
    <article>
      <p>John Ono Lennon, (born John Winston Lennon; 9 October 1940 – 8 December 1980), was an English musician, singer and songwriter who rose to worldwide fame as a founder member of the rock band the Beatles, the most commercially successful band in the history of popular music. With Paul McCartney, he formed a songwriting partnership that is one of the most celebrated of the 20th century.</p>
      <p>Born and raised in Liverpool, as a teenager Lennon became involved in the skiffle craze; his first band, the Quarrymen, evolved into the Beatles in 1960. When the group disbanded in 1970, Lennon embarked on a solo career that produced the critically acclaimed albums John Lennon/Plastic Ono Band and Imagine, and iconic songs such as "Give Peace a Chance" and "Working Class Hero". After his marriage to Yoko Ono in 1969, he changed his name to John Ono Lennon. Lennon disengaged himself from the music business in 1975 to raise his infant son Sean, but re-emerged with Ono in 1980 with the new album Double Fantasy. He was murdered three weeks after its release.</p>
    </article>
  </section>
  <section id="section2">
    <input type="radio" name="sections" id="option2">
    <label for="option2">2</label>
    <article>
      <h2>Paul McCartney</h2>
      <p>Sir James Paul McCartney, (born 18 June 1942), is an English musician, singer, songwriter, multi-instrumentalist, and composer. With John Lennon, George Harrison and Ringo Starr, he gained worldwide fame as a member of the Beatles, widely regarded as one of the most popular and influential acts in the history of rock music; his songwriting partnership with Lennon is one of the most celebrated of the 20th century. After the band's break-up, he pursued a solo career and later formed Wings with his first wife, Linda, and Denny Laine.</p>
      <p>McCartney has been recognised as one of the most successful composers and performers of all time, with 60 gold discs and sales of over 100 million albums and 100 million singles of his work with the Beatles and as a solo artist.[2] More than 2,200 artists have covered his Beatles song "Yesterday", more than any other copyrighted song in history. Wings' 1977 release "Mull of Kintyre" is one of the all-time best-selling singles in the UK. Inducted into the Rock and Roll Hall of Fame as a solo artist in March 1999, McCartney has written, or co-written 32 songs that have reached number one on the Billboard Hot 100, and as of 2014 he has sold more than 15.5 million RIAA-certified units in the United States. McCartney, Lennon, Harrison and Starr received MBEs in 1965, and in 1997, McCartney was knighted for his services to music.</p>
      <p>McCartney has released an extensive catalogue of songs as a solo artist and has composed classical and electronic music. He has taken part in projects to promote international charities related to such subjects as animal rights, seal hunting, land mines, vegetarianism, poverty, and music education. He has married three times and is the father of five children.</p>
    </article>
  </section>
  <section id="section3">
    <input type="radio" name="sections" id="option3">
    <label for="option3">3</label>
    <article>
      <h2>George Harrison</h2>
      <p>George Harrison, (25 February 1943 – 29 November 2001), was an English musician, multi-instrumentalist, singer and songwriter who achieved international fame as the lead guitarist of the Beatles. Although John Lennon and Paul McCartney were the band's primary songwriters, most of their albums included at least one Harrison composition, including "While My Guitar Gently Weeps", "Here Comes the Sun" and "Something", which became the Beatles' second-most-covered song.</p>
    </article>
  </section>
  <section id="section4">
    <input type="radio" name="sections" id="option4">
    <label for="option4">4</label>
    <article>
      <h2>Ringo Starr</h2>
      <p>Richard Starkey, (born 7 July 1940), better known by his stage name Ringo Starr, is an English musician, singer, songwriter, and actor who gained worldwide fame as the drummer for The Beatles. On most of the band's albums, he sang lead vocals for one song, including "With a Little Help from My Friends", "Yellow Submarine" and their cover of "Act Naturally". He also wrote the Beatles' songs "Don't Pass Me By" and "Octopus's Garden", and is credited as a co-writer of others, such as "What Goes On" and "Flying".</p>
      <p>Starr was twice afflicted by life-threatening illnesses during his childhood, and as a result of prolonged hospitalisations, fell behind scholastically. In 1955, he entered the workforce and briefly held a position with British Rail before securing an apprenticeship at a Liverpool equipment manufacturer. Soon afterwards, he became interested in the UK skiffle craze, developing a fervent admiration for the genre. In 1957, he cofounded his first band, the Eddie Clayton Skiffle Group, which earned several prestigious local bookings before the fad succumbed to American rock and roll by early 1958.</p>
    </article>
  </section>
  
   </section>
  <section id="section5">
    <input type="radio" name="sections" id="option5">
    <label for="option5">5</label>
    <article>
      <h2>Ringo Starr</h2>
      <p>Richard Starkey, (born 7 July 1940), better known by his stage name Ringo Starr, is an English musician, singer, songwriter, and actor who gained worldwide fame as the drummer for The Beatles. On most of the band's albums, he sang lead vocals for one song, including "With a Little Help from My Friends", "Yellow Submarine" and their cover of "Act Naturally". He also wrote the Beatles' songs "Don't Pass Me By" and "Octopus's Garden", and is credited as a co-writer of others, such as "What Goes On" and "Flying".</p>
      <p>Starr was twice afflicted by life-threatening illnesses during his childhood, and as a result of prolonged hospitalisations, fell behind scholastically. In 1955, he entered the workforce and briefly held a position with British Rail before securing an apprenticeship at a Liverpool equipment manufacturer. Soon afterwards, he became interested in the UK skiffle craze, developing a fervent admiration for the genre. In 1957, he cofounded his first band, the Eddie Clayton Skiffle Group, which earned several prestigious local bookings before the fad succumbed to American rock and roll by early 1958.</p>
    </article>
  </section>
  
 </section>
  <section id="section6">
    <input type="radio" name="sections" id="option6">
    <label for="option6">6</label>
    <article>
      <h2>Ringo Starr</h2>
      <p>Richard Starkey, (born 7 July 1940), better known by his stage name Ringo Starr, is an English musician, singer, songwriter, and actor who gained worldwide fame as the drummer for The Beatles. On most of the band's albums, he sang lead vocals for one song, including "With a Little Help from My Friends", "Yellow Submarine" and their cover of "Act Naturally". He also wrote the Beatles' songs "Don't Pass Me By" and "Octopus's Garden", and is credited as a co-writer of others, such as "What Goes On" and "Flying".</p>
      <p>Starr was twice afflicted by life-threatening illnesses during his childhood, and as a result of prolonged hospitalisations, fell behind scholastically. In 1955, he entered the workforce and briefly held a position with British Rail before securing an apprenticeship at a Liverpool equipment manufacturer. Soon afterwards, he became interested in the UK skiffle craze, developing a fervent admiration for the genre. In 1957, he cofounded his first band, the Eddie Clayton Skiffle Group, which earned several prestigious local bookings before the fad succumbed to American rock and roll by early 1958.</p>
    </article>
  </section>

 </section>
  <section id="section7">
    <input type="radio" name="sections" id="option7">
    <label for="option7">7</label>
    <article>
      <h2>Ringo Starr</h2>
      <p>Richard Starkey, (born 7 July 1940), better known by his stage name Ringo Starr, is an English musician, singer, songwriter, and actor who gained worldwide fame as the drummer for The Beatles. On most of the band's albums, he sang lead vocals for one song, including "With a Little Help from My Friends", "Yellow Submarine" and their cover of "Act Naturally". He also wrote the Beatles' songs "Don't Pass Me By" and "Octopus's Garden", and is credited as a co-writer of others, such as "What Goes On" and "Flying".</p>
      <p>Starr was twice afflicted by life-threatening illnesses during his childhood, and as a result of prolonged hospitalisations, fell behind scholastically. In 1955, he entered the workforce and briefly held a position with British Rail before securing an apprenticeship at a Liverpool equipment manufacturer. Soon afterwards, he became interested in the UK skiffle craze, developing a fervent admiration for the genre. In 1957, he cofounded his first band, the Eddie Clayton Skiffle Group, which earned several prestigious local bookings before the fad succumbed to American rock and roll by early 1958.</p>
    </article>
  </section>

</div>

    <!-- tab -->
    <!-- tab -->
```

Answer (score 0):

EGCs answer will work for you.

You can also add `::nth-of-type(1)` and `::nth-last-of-type(1)` to the end of the class.

This tells the CSS that any first and last sibling element using that class should include the extra styles.

```
.tabordion label::nth-of-type(1) {
  border-top-left-radius:8px;
  border-top-right-radius:8px;
}

.tabordion label::nth-last-of-type(1) {
  border-bottom-left-radius:8px;
  border-bottom-right-radius:8px;
}
```

Comment: You can also use a shorthand of border-raduis property https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-radius

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and i though this one was going to work because it makes sense, but its not working either for both the first or the last element the extra style its not going off